# Observability of Gravity in SLAM

Tags: slam, imu, estimation

A number of SLAM systems only optimize over 4 variables(location and yaw) as they argue gravity is observable which constrains roll and pitch.

I don't understand this argument since in theory you still don't know what is causing acceleration, either gravity or movement. Can someone clarify this?